# phpmyadmin wont work on fresh ubuntu 12.04 vb setup

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, phpmyadmin

I regularly set up virtualbox ubuntu setups to run as local webservers. I have set these up several times and never had an issue. However, something has changed:

1)vb guest additions no longer allow me to copy and paste (i'll worry about that later)

2)more importantly phpmyadmin no longer works as installed - Initially going to localhost/phpmyadmin gave a message that the page could not be found.

So followed instructions which told me to do this in /var/www:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin phpmyadmin
```

which has created a phpmyadmin directory in /var/www but now I get an error saying: the mysqli extension is missing.

If I run phpinfo mysql and mysqli are listed.

All I have done so far is

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo apt-get install php5
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

I found a post of a similar question which suggested I should do

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

(I've done this) and edit php.ini and uncomment the line:

```
extension=mysqli.so
```

This is not there, so I tried adding it but no joy. I have restarted apache and still no phpmyadmin.

I'm running a windows 7 machine and the guest os is ubuntu 12.04

Comment: I personally prefer to use the MySQL Workbench app : http://www.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/  ,  especially if your adminstering from your Windows 7 machine.   The phpmyadmin app is from the days before "MySQL Workbench" was available...

Comment: I did have a play around with that at some point - I abandoned it because the free windows version doesnt work on remote servers. It would be a workaround for this but since all my live servers are running phpmyadmin I would prefer to keep it all consistent if possible. Besides, I don't like to admit defeat if I can help it - this should be simple... it used to be.

Comment: The free Windows version DOES work on remote servers.  I use it on Amazon EC2 servers all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I have found the answer to this.

**Dont do this step (not needed):**

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin phpmyadmin
```

**Dont do this step (not needed):**

```
edit php.ini and uncomment the line:

extension=mysqli.so
```

**Do do this:**

```
sudo ln -s /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf
```

Apparently this serves to "symlink the phpMyAdmin conf file within the apache2/conf.d/" courtesy of pete fisher: http://blog.peterfisher.me.uk/2012/06/27/solution-to-phpmyadmin-throwing-a-404-error/

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget to restart the apache after the ln command:

> sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart